# How to securely store phone numbers in Twilio Functions?

Tags: twilio-functions

I am using Twilio Functions. I wonder if the phone numbers stored in the Function's code are secure?

I am using code similar to that found here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180548-How-Can-I-Stop-Receiving-or-Block-Incoming-Phone-Calls-#blacklistNumbers

Basically, it rejects numbers that on a blacklist of your choosing. The blacklist is in the Function's code itself.

Perhaps this is already secure. Forgive my misunderstanding.

The aforementioned code:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // Listing all the blocked phone numbers, at the moment "+1(212)555-1234" and "+1(702)555-6789"
  let blacklist = event.blacklist || [ "+12125551234", "+17025556789" ];

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  let blocked = true;
  if (blacklist.length > 0) {
    if (blacklist.indexOf(event.From) === -1) {
      blocked = false;
    }
  }
  if (blocked) {
    twiml.reject();
  }
  else {
    // if the caller's number is not blocked, redirecting to another TwiML which includes instructions for what to do
    twiml.redirect("https://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml");
  }
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyooo. Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I don't think you have to worry about the security of these numbers. But what you could do it to add the blacklist to the [function configuration instead](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure). This way you wouldn't have to change the function code whenever you want to add a new number to the blacklist.

[image: Function configuration in twilio]

These values below will be available in the context object that is passed into your function.

[image: Blacklist as function parameter]

```
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log(context.BLACKLIST); // 1212...
}
```

Comment: All of this is exactly what I needed to know and hear. Thank you very much, Stefan.